# How to add github dependency in package.json if package.json of second project not in the root of the project

Tags: javascript, node.js, git, github

I'd like to add dependency in `package.json` on github project, but that github project does not have `package.json` in root of the project. Is it possible to do that?

My `package.json`:

```
"dependencies": {
"seg-qa": "myname/seg-qa.git",
"lodash": "^3.5.0",
"bluebird": "^3.5.1",
"moment": "^2.8.4" }
```

structure of the project `myname/seg-qa.git`:

```
apps/package.json
.drone
.gitignore
readme.md
```

But that project `"seg-qa": "myname/seg-qa.git"` does not have package.json in the root and I'm getting error:

1. `Non-registry package missing package.json: seg-qa@`
2. `npm can't find a package.json file in your current directory`

Anyone knows how can I add that project as dependency( I google it, did not really find answer for that)

Comment: this can be useful: https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#git-urls-as-dependencies

Answer (score 0):

I also tries it and failed.
It seems to be a limitation.

*Hack*: you can clone the second repo locally, and state your dep as a [local path](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#local-paths)

Answer (score -3):

npm init
create a package.json file.